# Tab1 data is still visible when tab2 is clicked

Tags: html, css

I want to create web page using pure **html,css and javascript**. I have created a webpage which contains multiple tabs.
Each tab shows data loading from different html files.
Please find the code below:

```
<div class="tabs">
    <div class="tab">
        <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
        <label for="tab-1">Tab1</label>
       <!-- <div class="content">
            <iframe src="tab1.html">
            </iframe>
        </div> -->
          <div class="content" style="width:700px;height:700px;">
           <!-- <embed type="text/html" src="summary.html"> -->
             <iframe src="tab1.html"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
   <div class="tab">
        <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1">
        <label for="tab-2">Tab2</label>
        <div class="content">
           <iframe src="tab2.html"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
        <input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1">
        <label for="tab-3">Tab3</label>
        <div class="content">
           <iframe src="tab3.html"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I was trying to fix the below items:

When user click on tab1, the content is displayed and again when user clicks on Tab2 , still the Tab1 content can be viewed as shown in the fiddle below.

[Fiddle](https://plnkr.co/edit/Xs9C9eWKUYBI32hXqSWc?p=preview)

Comment: the problem is that tab1 doesn't just disappear when you click it, it is overlayed by the other tabs. you could try hiding its content when you click in the other tabs.

Comment: @sebasaenz - can u please suggest how to implement using javascript as i tried finding out the solution but could not find the appropriate one using javascript. I cannot use any other frameworks so need to achieve this using javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need some more minor things:

```
        [type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
            z-index: 1;
            display: block;
        }

        [type=radio] ~ .content
        {
            display: none;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not hiding the tab instead you are overlaying each tab.. the `html` you've done is correct. .only your css need a little line of code

add `display: none;` on you `content` class

and then add this block

```
    [type=radio]:checked ~ .content {
      display: block !important;
    }
```

this will show the `div.content` within your `radio:checked`

plunker: [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/0TM189YqRfaSmeu5INlN?p=preview)